# Specified X axes limits changes when updating the plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-guide

I have a data set that is updating in a loop. My `X-Axes` data start from 0 and I have a new value for `X` and `Y` in every iteration of loop. When I start the GUI everything is fine. The plot starts updating but sometimes in a middle of process I have something like this :

[image]

before that everything was fine and the plot started from `1` but in this step suddenly the plot will break and we have `0` in `X-Axes`. I want show the results from `1` only. There isn't any `0` value for `X-Axes` in my updating data set in the loop. I changed `XlimMode` properties of plot from manual to auto but didn't help. I'm using MATLAB R2014b.

Comment: @Adiel `data(end)`, not `end(data)`

Comment: After the plot command, write `xlim([1 data(end)])`. Thanks @excaza!

Comment: @Adiel Should I refer to handle of the plot in `xlim`? my handle for this plot is `handles.ploting`

Comment: @user2991243 What about triying it? If it doesnt work wothout the handles, then give it the handles!

Comment: If you write it right after the `plot` command, so it works on the current axis, i.e. the axis that you just plotted.

Comment: @Adiel. thank you. please add your answer.